# C# WPF project, how to avoid InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a WPF project. I got the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

I try to get value from a TextBox from a worker thread created by me.

How to avoid this.  I was able to avoid this in another Form project by using `delegate` call back and `Invoked()` method but somehow it doesn't work in this WPF project.

any simple sample code? thanks,

Comment: Or ThreadPool thread - but in any case, if he wants to get the Text from the TextBox, he'll need the dispatcher... It really doesn't matter which method of threading he's using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247269/wpf-event-threading-gui-updating-question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261248/wpf-thread-and-gui-how-to-access-object-from-different-thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792129/multithreaded-access-to-the-wpf-gui-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker

Comment: It really doesn't matter what threading technique you're using - the answer's still Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something along the lines of:

```
        if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) 
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (MyDelegate)delegate
            {
                // Get value
            });
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Get value
        }
```

Comment: after doing that, I got this error: "TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch." Could you help me?

Comment: I suspect the delegate you've declared takes a parameter, and you haven't supplied one. You can use the built in "Action" delegate in place of "MyDelegate" above if you have no need for parameters.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the Dispatcher to handle this.  Instead of using Control.Invoke like in Windows Forms, you now need to use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) or [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) to marshal your call back onto the UI thread.